# Reading byte array the second time causes error?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, arrays, flash

I am using the following code to read an error message from a byte array and it works fine the first time but if I try to access it the second time it throws an error:

```
errorData = process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable);
```

StandardError is of type InboundPipe?

The error is:

```
Error: Error #3212: Cannot perform operation on a NativeProcess that is not running.
```

even though the process is running (process.running is true). It's on the second call to readUTFBytes that seems to be the cause.

**Update:**
Here is the code calling the same call one after another. The error happens on the next line and process.running has not changed from true. Happens on the second call.

```
errorData = process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable);
errorData = process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable);
```

I also found out the standardError is a **InboundPipe** instance and implements **IDataInput**.

**Update 2:**
Thanks for all the help. I found this documentation when viewing the bytesAvailable property.

> [Read Only] Returns the number of bytes of data available for reading
>   in the input buffer. User code must call `bytesAvailable` to ensure that
>   sufficient data is available before trying to read it with one of the
>   read methods.

When I call readUTFBytes() it resets the bytes available to 0. So when I read it a second time and there are no bytes available it causes the error. The error is or may be incorrect in my opinion or the native process.running flag is incorrect.

I looked into seeing if it has a `position` property and it does not, at least not in this instance.

Comment: Did you try reading one UTF character per call once there's more than 1? Does it still throw an error, if so?

Comment: Is it one function that does both trace of runningIsTrue and also readUTFbytes? If yes then I'm stumped why it claims "true" but then immediately fails like its "false". I'm interested in the answer. However if you have a separate function for 2nd call just check that the process was not stopped by some other code. Hope you get it. It's a tough one (maybe a bug?)...

Comment: I think the error message is a bug the process appears to still be running (no exit event) and there's documentation that says you must check if bytesAvailable is not 0 before trying to read the input. The InboundPipe shares the same Interface as ByteArray but it does not extend from it, thus the difference in behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky problem since the object was not a byte array although it looks and acts like one (same methods and almost same properties). It is an InboundPipe that also implements IDataInput.

I found this documentation when viewing the `bytesAvailable` property.

> [Read Only] Returns the number of bytes of data available for reading
>   in the input buffer. User code must call `bytesAvailable` to ensure that
>   sufficient data is available *before* trying to read it with one of the
>   read methods.

When I call `readUTFBytes()` it resets the bytes available to 0. So when I call it a second time and there are no bytes available it causes the error. The error is or may be incorrect in my opinion or the native process.running flag is incorrect although I have reason to believe it's the former.

The solution is to check bytesAvailable before calling read operations and store the value if it needs to be accessed later.

```
if (process.standardError.bytesAvailable) {
    errorData = process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable);
    errorDataArray.push(errorData);
}
```

I looked into seeing if it has a position property and it does not, at least not in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try to set `position` to zero before reading process, especially before repetitive access:

> Moves, or returns the current position, in bytes, of the file pointer into the ByteArray object. This is the point at which the next call to a read method starts reading or a write method starts writing.

```
//ByteArray example
var source: String = "Some data";
var data: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
data.writeUTFBytes(source);
data.position = 0;
trace(data.readUTFBytes(data.bytesAvailable));
data.position = 0;
trace(data.readUTFBytes(data.bytesAvailable));
```

Comment: That'll be good if the ByteArray in question would be a regular one, but here it's the pipe, so rewinding that does no good.

Comment: As for pipe, result should be stored after first access.

Comment: Once you use any of the read() methods, that byte is essentially gone (or rather, the position gets updated +1 for the next read() method). you cannot read it twice unless you reset the position to 0 as Nicolas suggests.

Comment: @NicolasSiver Imagine that a process sends more than 1 error at a time to its standard error channel. You catch one "data available" event, then another, and bam you can't read out of that pipe the second time. Rewinding, if possible and if implemented, will at most net you the first error message, but you are interested in the second one.

Comment: It appears the byteArray doesn't support rewinding. It doesn't have a position property. Once the bytes are read then the bytes available is set to 0. It appears to be a once access type of thing. I'll add more to the question notes.

Comment: Update to the last comment, it's not a byteArray. It extends from Object. The only documentation reference I found is in russian AS3 docs, http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/InboundPipe.html.